# Can An Android Application stop the user recording Audio/Video

Tags: android, security, video-capture, audio-recording

I am developing a building access Android Application.

The Application will allow the user to preset their identity and vehicle registration details etc.

When they enter a building the application will automatically log them in and track their movements while in the building.

For extra security I do not wish to allow the building visitor to use their device to record either Audio, Video or photography of any type.

I cannot find any API's and/or "features" within Android that will allow me to disable the devices camera or audio recording facilities.

Is there any way I can stop the visitor from recording Audio and/or Video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will provide a device to the visitors? or do you want to block they personal devices?

If you want to block their personal devices then no, you cannot do this.
If you will provide the device to them then there are a few thing you can do but i don't know at witch extend you want to go. You can replace the launcher on the device with a custom one and block all the camera / video apps, including the app store. There are a few out there that will allow you to set a password for hidden apps. (Smart Launcher).

But you will also need to get a device than don't do things like opening the camera on double power button tap (The nexus 5x does this but it can be turned off) and change the notification screen as well.

In the end you will eventually require to root the device and maybe use a custom ROM that allows you to customize a lot of the phone behavior. ROMs like cyanogen will allow this, but again, it depends a lot on your device and how far you want to take the app blocking.

Comment: I wish to develop an application that the Visitor installs on their personal device. This application should block audio and visual recording.

Comment: i don't think you can do that. It will require at least root access to the phone.